# Select certain column only if condition met

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to have a select that will not have fixed number of columns.
Column `OptionalColumn` should be selected only if variable *@check* = 1

This is what I had (syntax is bad but maybe it explains my problem)

```
SELECT 
    Column1, Column2,
    (IF @Check = 1
       BEGIN OptionalColumn END)
FROM table
```

It is crucial to have it only if @Check = 1 and not having it if @Check = 0.
Is it doable?

Comment: If you really want to exclude this column(not only a `NULL` value) then you should use a stored-procedure or a table-valued function and an `IF...ELSE`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is horrible design. If you are sure this is something you need, solve it in a different way; have logic to determine what the value of @check1 is, and based on that outcome, pull data from 2 views; 1 with the column, and 1 without the column, and have your front-end expose or hide the column that way.

Comment: A SQL query returns a pre-defined set of columns.  There is no such concept as "optional columns" for a `SELECT`.  As @TimSchmelter says, you need to use dynamic SQL or separate `IF` statements.

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's  **column** - one "l" is QUITE enough !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with an IF ELSE block like this;

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Column1 varchar(10), Column2 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #table
VALUES
('column1', 'column2')

DECLARE @Check bit; SET @Check = 0

IF @Check = 1 
(SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM #table)

ELSE

(SELECT Column1
FROM #table)
```

Change the variable from 0 to 1 for testing to see the change in number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Rich Benner gave you a good solution, as an alternative you can use dynamic sql like that :

```
DECLARE  @sqlvar VARCHAR(100)
select @Sqlvar= ' SELECT Column1, Column2 '+IIF (@check=1,',OptionalColumn','')+' from TABLE';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlvar
```

For reference on sp_ executesql  look:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx]

Comment: Dynamic SQL is a bit higher on the complexity scale, and might be a tad overkill for this situation. Having said that, it's still a really useful thing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Can use IF ELSE block. Please try this.

```
--Creating a Table.
CREATE TABLE #MyTable 
    (
    Column1 VARCHAR(10), 
    Column2 VARCHAR(10),
    OptionalColumn VARCHAR(10)
    )
--Inserting value to the Table.
INSERT INTO #MyTable
VALUES('Value 1', 'Value 1','Optional Value')

--IF ELSE Logic to desired output.
DECLARE @Check bit 
SET @Check = 0

IF @Check = 1 
    (
    SELECT 
        Column1, 
        Column2
    FROM 
        #MyTable
    )
ELSE
   (
    SELECT 
        Column1, 
        Column2,
        OptionalColumn
    FROM 
        #MyTable
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that it's pretty clean and readable to use temp tables for this purpose, and it doesn't require duplicating queries or big branches of logic.

Create a temp table with all the columns you would ever need. Use IF statements to drop the columns you don't want to display from the temp table. Then finally, select * from the temp table.

This will also allow you use the data returned to make a determination on whether to keep the column or not.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable;
 select '---' as [1],
 '---' as [2],
 '---' as [3],
 '---' as [4],
 '---' as [5],
 '---' as [6],
 '---' as [7],
 null as [8]
 into #tempTable 

if RAND() > .5
begin
    alter table #tempTable drop column [1]
end

if RAND() > .5
begin
    alter table #tempTable drop column [2]
end

if RAND() > .5
begin
    alter table #tempTable drop column [3]
end

--Query using result set to dertmine if column should be dropped
if (select count(*) from #tempTable where [8] is not null) = 0
begin
    alter table #tempTable drop column [8]
end

select * from  #tempTable
```